# Usage of POST in R

Tags: r, json, rest, post

I am trying to call API from R but I am somehow getting Status 403 message.

CSV To JSON Conversion :

```
x<-  list(internalId = Attributes$internalId,  description = list(language = Attributes$description.language,
                 short = Attributes$description.short,
                 long = Attributes$description.long),  dimension1 = Attributes$dimension1)
```

Please find the code for POST below :

```
PResponse <- POST(POSTURL,
              config = list(authenticate(username, password),
                          add_headers("x-csrf-token"=csrf,"Accept"="application/json")),
                          body = cat(RJSONIO::toJSON(x))
              )
```

Comment: Want to know if there is any mistake in calling the POST function?

Comment: No data. No library calls. Apparent lack of understanding of open source aspect of R.

Comment: I am using HTTR and RJSONIO library here.